# Access VBA to split out ALL merged cell in Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, ms-access-2007

I need to import some Excel files into Access database. I know how to write the import function in VBA but it is not working as I expected since some merged cell in Excel cause me trouble.

So for example, in the Excel spreadsheet

[image]

When importing to Access table, it imported row by row . So the 1st row should be 1-pencil-90, and it is correct but the 2nd and 3rd row is empty due to the merged cell.
The result is

```
No|Product|Storage
1 | pencil|90
  |       |23
  |       |41
```

But expected result should be:

```
No|Product|Storage
1 | pencil|90
1 | pencil|23
1 | pencil|41
```

I want the VBA to split the merged cells and also fill in the blank data with the information in the merged cell. Please keep in mind that I got a lot of merged cells and manually change is impossible. I am open to any solution that help me achieve the desire result.

P/S: The aata can be left blank so I can't use conditional check if it blank then look up the above data.

Comment: If you want to do unmergeing without a macro (or you can prepare one, assuming you havae build the import one) you can Select your data unmerge it and use this magic used here [HERE](http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/10/17/fill-blank-cells-in-a-table/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub UnMergeRanges()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rMerged As Range
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cl.MergeCells Then
            Set rMerged = cl.MergeArea
            v = rMerged.Cells(1, 1)
            rMerged.MergeCells = False
            rMerged = v
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

How it works:

- Loop through cells in the used range
- If the cell is part of a merged range

  - Set a Range variable to the Merged Range
  - Record the current value of the Top Left cell in the range into a variable `v`.  This is the value the merged range displays
  - Unmerge the range
  - write the recorded value (`v`) into all cells of the now unmerged range

Comment: can I ask what is the purpose of this line "v = rMerged.Cells(1, 1) " ?