# Check merged cell and compare adjacent to set unique value from compared cells values

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I'm writing a macro in Excel 2010 for a problem that is as follows: 
I have two columns, one with a Key string value and one with a uuid. The idea is that every key should have only one uuid but as the table is now, key cell could be merged cells or single cells.
The macro needs to recognize which cells are merged and which are not, so, I have two options:

- If cell is merged, check all its adjacent cells, pick first uuid value and copy/paste it to other adjacent cells, that is to say, cell below(Could be with an `Offset()`)
- If cell is not merged , but key value is repeated in multiple cells, copy/paste uuid value to adjacent cells.

So basically is to check merged cells `MergeArea` but I don't know if I need to iterate through its addresses or check cells in the range with an offset of `Offset(0,1)` or what.
With my code I can know if the cells are merged but now, how con I iterate through it's adjacent cells values?

Code as is now:

```
Sub CopyUUID()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rMerged As Range
Dim value As Variant

Set ws = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

On Error GoTo ExitProgram 'If an error happens within the execution, skips it and continue in next step
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'We can cancel the procedure without errors

With ws
    lRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(3, 6), .Cells(lRow, 6))
    rng.Select
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.MergeCells Then
            'Code for merged cells
        Else
            'Code to use for single cells
        End If
    Next cell
End With
ExitProgram:
   Exit Sub
End Sub
```

[image: Table Example]

Comment: I was reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720395/access-vba-to-split-out-all-merged-cell-in-excel) and it seems I can access merged cell range but as my cells could be result of merging 2 or more without previously knowing it, how can I make it generic?

Comment: Which one is column F Key or UUID? Also, are the merged cells always in one column?

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't clarify that. F column is key's one and yes, merged cells are only in Key column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. Note that this is going to overwrite the current contents of UUID, so make a backup copy before testing. If you don't want the UUID column modified, you can modify this to suit your needs.

```
Sub CopyUUID()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rMerged As Range
    Dim value As Variant

    Set ws = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

    On Error GoTo ExitProgram 'If an error happens within the execution, skips it and continue in next step
    ' Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'We can cancel the procedure without errors

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(3, 6), .Cells(lRow, 6))
        ' rng.Select
        For Each c In rng

            If c.MergeCells Then
                'Code for merged cells
                c.Offset(0, 1).Formula = c.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 1).Formula
            Else
                'Code to use for single cells
                If c.Formula = c.Offset(-1, 0).Formula Then
                    c.Offset(0, 1).Formula = c.Offset(-1, 1).Formula
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End With
    ExitProgram:
       Exit Sub
End Sub
```

When in a MergedCell, it makes the UUID the same as the UUID of the first cell in the merged area. When not in a MergedCell, it copies UUID from the row above if Key is the same as the row above.

I changed your variable `cell` to `c` (I don't like to use variable names that can be confused with built-ins) and commented out a couple of lines.

Hope this helps

Comment: What is the formula method for?

Comment: Not working as I should. Some additional info: Key and UUID columns are not adjacent, Key colum has an index value of 6( column #6) and uuid column of 31 so, I modified your code as per those offsets but no use. Don't know If I'm doing it wrong.
`If c.MergeCells Then c.Offset(3, 31).Formula = c.MergeArea.Cells(1, 31).Offset(0, 31).Formula Else If c.Formula = c.Offset(-1, 31).Formula Then c.Offset(0, 31).Formula = c.Offset(-1, 31).Formula End If End If Next c`

Comment: Range.Formula gets/sets the formula in a cell. It can be an excel formula, e.g., `=PI()` or a constant e.g. `UUID`. If the data you're working on contains only string constants then you could also use Range.Value.

Comment: For merged cells use `c.Offset(0, 25).Formula = c.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 25).Formula`. For unmerged cells use `c.Offset(0, 25).Formula = c.Offset(-1, 25).Formula`. If Keys are in column 6, offsetting by 25 columns gets you to column 31 for UUIDs

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyUUID()

    Const UUID As Long = 31 'col AE

    Dim lRow As Long, cel As Range, isM As Boolean, copyID As Boolean, kCol As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        kCol = -25          'col F
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, UUID + kCol).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each cel In .Range(.Cells(3, UUID), .Cells(lRow, UUID))

            isM = cel.Offset(0, kCol).MergeCells
            copyID = isM And Len(cel.Offset(0, kCol)) = 0
            copyID = copyID Or (Not isM And cel.Offset(0, kCol) = cel.Offset(-1, kCol))

            If copyID Then cel = cel.Offset(-1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to tell, "Key" column is, as my example, in column F (index 6) but uuid column is at column AE (index 31)

Answer (score 0):

I adopt a simple approach to this problem as illustrated through steps taken by me.

1. sample sheet showing data with merged cells and unmerged cells.
   [image: sample data]
2. Run the program code to unmerge the cells. Output of the program is appended below.

[image: Unmerged Sample data First stage]

3. If this structure of data matches your case then addition of 2 lines of code for column B will leave the data as per following image.

[image: unmerged data after deleting column through program code]

4. Program code is as follows:

'Without column deletion:

```
Sub UnMergeRanges()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rMerged As Range
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cl.MergeCells Then
            Set rMerged = cl.MergeArea
            v = rMerged.Cells(1, 1)
            rMerged.MergeCells = False
            rMerged = v
        End If
    Next
End Sub
'With coumn deletion   
Sub UnMergeRangesB()
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rMerged As Range
    Dim v As Variant

    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cl.MergeCells Then
            Set rMerged = cl.MergeArea
            v = rMerged.Cells(1, 1)
            rMerged.MergeCells = False
            rMerged = v
        End If
    Next
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: But I don't have any merged column. "Key" columns is composed of column merged cells and single cells. Besides, I don't need to unmerge them, I need to set a unique value for n different cells that are adjacent to a merged or a single cell.

Comment: I followed your initial image and assumed structure of cells. After going through intervening comments, perhaps it may be preferable for you to go for more customized program to suit your needs.